# PHP - Nested Ternary Operators

Tags: php, ternary-operator

Having a little bit of trouble, I'm trying to get $letterGrade assigned letters, but it seems to only assign D and F.

```
 ($finalGrade >= 97) ? $letterGrade = "A+" 
        : ($finalGrade >= 93 && $finalGrade <97) ? $letterGrade = "A"
        : ($finalGrade >= 90 && $finalGrade <93) ? $letterGrade = "A-"
        : ($finalGrade >= 87 && $finalGrade <90) ? $letterGrade = "B+"
        : ($finalGrade >= 83 && $finalGrade <87) ? $letterGrade = "B"
        : ($finalGrade >= 80 && $finalGrade< 83) ? $letterGrade = "B-"
        : ($finalGrade >= 77 && $finalGrade <80) ? $letterGrade = "C+"
        : ($finalGrade >= 73 && $finalGrade <77) ? $letterGrade = "C"
        : ($finalGrade >= 70 && $finalGrade <73) ? $letterGrade = "C-"
        : ($finalGrade >= 60 && $finalGrade <70) ? $letterGrade = "D"
        : $letterGrade = "F"
        ;
```

Comment: Don't nest ternary operators. Use a switch statement instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using ternary operators for this, use a [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement. For example:

```
switch ($finalGrade) {
    case ($finalGrade >= 93 && $finalGrade < 97):
    $letterGrade = "A";
    break;
    //continue $finalGrade checks
}
```

You can also use an [`elseif`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) statement.

```
if ($finalGrade >= 93 && $finalGrade < 97) { 
$lettergrade = "A";
}
elseif($finalGrade >= 90 && $finalGrade < 93) {
$letterGrade = "A-";
}
elseif($finalGrade >= 87 && $finalGrade < 90) {
$letterGrade = "B+";
}
//...continue checks....
else {
$letterGrade = "F";
}
```